# Track click over iframe by Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

how can we track clicks on iframe (like any advt.) and record that event in my own database (with ajax) according to website users respectively with advt id and user id

1. i have tried onclick (like below) event on parent div but not working -

   ```js
           $('div.ad').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
             url: 'clickevent.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {
              'id': adId
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
              // show success msg to user
             },
             error: function(){
              // show failure msg
             }
            });
           });
   ```
2. i tried focus and blur while cursor is over that iframe

   ```js
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
       <script>
       jQuery(function( $ ){
               var isOverAd = false;
               $( "iframe[ id *= google ]" )
                   .mouseover(function(){
                           isOverAd = true;
                       })
                   .mouseout(function(){
                           isOverAd = false;
                       });
               $( window ).blur(
                   function(){
                       if (isOverAd){
                           $.ajax({
                               url: 'clickevent.php',
                               type: 'POST',
                               data: {
                                   'id': adId
                               },
                               dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                 //show success msg
                },
                error: function(){
                 //show failure msg
                }
                           });
                       }
                   }).focus();
           });
   ```
3. i have also tried for when window loss blur while mouse on that iframe
4. i have mapped pixels ($0 values) it is also not working.

but nothing is working ......i will be very thankfull if you help me

Comment: This error shows that you did not add a jquery file to your page.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi no actually i have did tht in my project but here i have only posted my codes

Comment: So the code snippet you created is useless.

Answer (score 0):

To access an frame in page you can do this:

```
var frame = window.frames['FRAME-ID'];
$(frame).load(function ()
{
    $(frame).contents().find('ELEMENT-IN-FRAME');
    //To manage click on element body ( or any elements):
    $(frame).contents().find('body').on('click', function(){alert('k')});
```

Comment: but how can i  know that the user clicked that iframe or any link inside that frame to register that event in my db ?